# CS Cart Rewrite Vendor URL

Tags: .htaccess, cs-cart

I need to change my vendor url

**From**
mysite.com/vendor.php?dispatch=auth.login_form&return_url=vendor.php

**To**

mysite.com/vendor-login

Can someone provide me solution?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Webiste > SEO > SEO Rules and add the URL there.

Kind regards,

Comment: This steps only change the dispatch value of index.php

Comment: @ShaanSetia Then I suggest you add a new mode by extending the 'login_form' with the exact same code as in the 'login_form' mode and hardcode the return_url variable in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the vendor.php to aything you consider is better but you need to keep .php extension

```
config.local.php
```

[image]

PS: vendor.php is not relevant for SEO, is not indexed, is only for vendors to manage their orders/users/products ...